# retrieving array from pointer array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

i have the following code

```
 int arr[5];
        printf("Input values:");
        for (i=0;i<5;i++)
        scanf("%d",&arr[i]);
        pthread_create(&thread1, NULL, &inputfunction, (void *)&arr);
        pthread_join(thread1,NULL);
        return 0;
}

void *inputfunction(void *ptr_value)
{
        int value= *((int *) ptr_value);
        printf("value=%d", value);
//      printf(&(ptr_value));
        return NULL;
}
```

I want to retrieve all the 5 values I have entered in the array but using this code in the body of the function returns just the first value. I am very confused with pointers and am not able to figure out the way to get the entire array.

please tell me what is the modification I need to make in my code.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
pthread_create(&thread1, NULL, &inputfunction, &(arr[0]));

void *inputfunction(void *ptr_value)
{
    int *values = ptr_value;

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
         printf("value %i = %i\n", i, values[i]);

    return NULL;
}
```

Comment: Should cast ptr_value to int* before assigning to values, just to be anal about it.

Comment: @ScottHunter: That's unnecessary in C.

Comment: @RichaSachdev it's not necessary, but makes the intent clearer.